# Proving Hopf bifurcations for 3D system

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, bifurcation

I am working with a 3D continuous system of ODEs. I have found Hopf bifurcation numerically for a certain value of parameter. However, I want prove it analytically. Is it enough to show that the eigenvalues cross the imaginary axis and equilibria change their stability for that certain parameter value?

Comment: You have to prove 2 things: 1). The jacobian has a pair of purely imaginary e.values at bifurcation point. 2) The derivative of real part of this pair of eigenvalues w.r.t to parameter is non-zero at bifurcation point. From these two conditions, the Hopf bifurcation follows. See: "Elementary Stability and Bifurcation theory", Iooss and Joseph.